# Google MapView zoomout to span a circle

Tags: android

I have a MapView centered at point P. The user can't change the MapView center, but he can choose a radius of a circle to be display around point P, and change it dynamically with the map being redrawn at each change to show the new circle.
The thing is, i want the map to zoom in or out as necessary, in order to display the entire circle at the viewable area. I've tried this:

```
Projection proj = m_Map.getProjection();
Point mapCenterPixles = new Point();
proj.toMapPixels(center, mapCenterPixles);
float radiusPixels = proj.metersToEquatorPixels(newRadius);

IGeoPoint topLeft = proj.fromPixels(mapCenterPixles.x - radiusPixels,
        mapCenterPixles.y - radiusPixels);
IGeoPoint bottomRight = proj.fromPixels(mapCenterPixles.x
        + radiusPixels, mapCenterPixles.y + radiusPixels);

m_Map.getController().zoomToSpan(
        topLeft.getLatitudeE6() - bottomRight.getLatitudeE6(),
        topLeft.getLongitudeE6() - bottomRight.getLongitudeE6());
```

But it seems i'm missing something, as the values passed to zoomToSpan() cause no chnage, I'm kind of lost here, can someone please shed some light on how to zoom the map to span a bounding box of the circle given its radius in meters, and its center points?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps zoom levels are defined in powers of two, so `MapController#zoomToSpan()` also zooms by powers of two.

Ergo, if the span you compute above is already displayable within the current zoom level, it's likely nothing would actually change visually in the map until you need to go to the next larger or smaller zoom level.

This behavior is somewhat vaguely described in the documentation for [MapController#zoomToSpan](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html#zoomToSpan%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Aside from the vague behavior, are my calculations right? i didn't fully understand the meaning of span, but followed few examples i found. Maybe i'm miscalculating, resulting in a span already displayed on screen?

Comment: I think it's mostly correct, except that the longitude of `bottomRight` is probably greater than that of `topLeft`, so you might want to use `bottomRight.getLongitudeE6() - topLeft.getLongitudeE6()` instead. And be aware that your code might break down near the [180th meridian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180th_meridian).